# mongoose .populate() find() match

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

How to find blog by category?
My schema:

```
var categorySchema = new Schema({
slug: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
name: { type: String, required: true},
});

var blogSchema = new Schema({
slug: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
name: { type: String, required: true },
category: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
content: String
});
```

model

```
var Category = mongoose.model('category', categorySchema);
var Blog = mongoose.model('blog', blogSchema);
```

I try:

```
Blog.find()
    .populate('category', 'slug name', {slug: req.params.slug })
    .exec(function(error, data){
        if(error)
            res.json({success: 0});
        else
            res.json({success: 1, data: data});
    });
```

but results:

data: [{
...
category: {
slug: "funny",
name: "Funny"
}
...,
{
slug: "some-thing-2",
name: "Some Thing 2",
category: null, <-- **HERE**
content: "My content 2"
}]

category 2 is null.

Comment: Have you check there is one document match the value of `req.params.slug` or the value of `req.params.slug` is correct value you want?

Comment: thank you, but some results ok, some results have category: null

Comment: [{
slug: "some-thing",
name: "Some Thing",
category: {
slug: "funny",
name: "Funny"
},
content: "My content"
},
{
slug: "some-thing-2",
name: "Some Thing 2",
category: null, <---Here
content: "My content 2"
}]

Comment: The category is also `null` in mongodb? or it indeed has one value...

Comment: It seems like the data of `category` is null for the second `slug`